# Algorithm to find number of palindromes in interval

Tags: c, optimization, palindrome, radix

I'm currently tasked with writing a program that calculates amount of palindromes in any base from interval of `<2;36>`. The problem is that my solution has time complexity of `O(n^2)` at best and that is, if I was frank, really slow.

So far I've tried naive solutions such as converting all numbers from the interval to the base that is required, saving the conversion of the number to array and then checking each of the elements one by one.

This is what I've got so far :

```
int isTrue = 1;
int arr[64];

while(n > 0)
{
   arr[counter] = n % base;
   n = n / base;
   counter++;
}

for(int i = 0; i < counter; i ++)
{
   if(arr[i] != arr[counter - i - 1])
   {
      isTrue = 0;
      break;
   }
}
```

It is not good by any stretch, but it does work for the basic test. The problem is that I'm currently trying to solve bonus one which works with much bigger numbers.

By much bigger numbers I mean intervals that span billions of numbers, one of the inputs is for example this:

```
c 15 62103360044 155888062462
Result : 123502
```

Where c is task that the program is supposed to do (there was option of l which listed all palindromes which doesn't occur in the bonus tests), 15 is base and the two other numbers are the limits of the interval.

I'm supposed to count palindromes of five such intervals under one second and honestly, I'm pretty stuck.

I would appreciate any help, I'm sorry if I formatted my question wrongly or if it was too drawn out - This is the first time I've asked a question here.

Comment: *under one second* and `O(log n)` are different requirements. Which is the one you have?

Comment: Under one second

Comment: Then what is that in the title? Remove it as it looks not realistic.

Comment: Anyway, you rather *generate* a palindrome list by iterating on the first half of the number - naturally the second half will be the same number reversed. So if you think a bit about it you might even come up with an analytical solution taking about zero time.

Comment: Re “checking each of the elements one by one”: What? No. If the interval is, in decimal, from 100000 to 999,999, then there are exactly 900 palindromes. You do not need to count them individually. If the first three digits are 100, there is one palindrome starting that way, 100,001. For 101, there is also one: 101,101. If the base is, say, 16, then from 100,000 to FFF,FFF in base 16, there are F00 (base 16) palindromes (3840 decimal). What you need to do is figure out how to count the palindromes in irregular intervals (like 1234 to 6972) without counting individually.

Comment: Yes, the main problem is that I will not receive any regular intervals (if I'm not astronomically lucky, but then it wouldn't really be a decent solution anyway) so it really boils down to just counting the palindromes in irregular intervals.

Answer (score 0):

- Doing a palindrome check faster is a *minor* optimisation.
  Initially I would even use java's number to String conversion.
- What you want is to step through the interval in larger leaps.
- You can use recursion for simplification in the initial version of your algorithm.

Let's look for base 10:

```
 62_103_360_044
155_888_062_462

 6 ...        6 (recursion on the middle part)
 7 ...        7
 8 ...        8
 9 ...        9
1 ...         1
```

You need:

- Number of digits (your `counter`)
- First most significant digit
- Parameters start and end

For this step you only need to increment one digit, which even may be done as char.

Notice also that the recursive call on ... gives the same result for 7, 8 and 9 with start 000..000 and end 999..999.

This will be tremendously faster. Happy coding.

---

***Usage of recursion:***
*I am not giving a clean answer, as that would defeat the task's challenge.*

```
public BigInteger palindromesInInterval(int base, BigInteger from, BigInteger to) {
    return palindromesRec(base, from.toString(base), to.toString(base));
}

private BigInteger palindromesRec(int base, String from, String to) {
    // Do the simple work:
    if (from.length() > to.length()) {
        return BigInteger.ZERO;
    }
    if (from.length() == to.length() && from.compareTo(to) > 0) {
        return BigInteger.ZERO;
    }
    if (from.length() == 1) {
        ...
    }
    // Do a step:
    int highDigit = Integer.parseInt(from.substring(0, 1), base);
    int lowDigit = Integer.parseInt(from.substring(from.length() - 1), base);

    BigInteger sum = BigInteger.ZERO;
    int digit = Math.max(highDigit, lowDigit);
    String from2 = from.substring(1, from.length() - 2); // Can start with 0
    String to2 = "1000...000" -1; // Niners so to say.
    while (digit < base) {
         ...
         sum = sum.add(palidromesRec(base, from2, to2)); // RECURSION
         from2 = "000...000";
    }
    ...
    return sum;
}
```

Recursion calling oneself, here only once, without extra parameters, which often are used. For instance it is much easier to split the work in:

```
from  6 2_103_360_04 4
  to  9 9 ..       9 9

from 1 00 ..       0 1
  to 1 55_888_062_46 2
```

And calculate for every X

```
from X 000 X   (n zeroes)
  to X 999 X   (n time (base-1))
```

as base<sup>(n+1)/2</sup>.

For that you need a level of abstraction/simplification. Keep-it-simple.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not sure I completely follow : What do you mean by using recursion on middle part of the number and stepping through interval in larger steps? I

Comment: Was _recursion_ treated? Doing just a tiny bit, the surrounding digit, and calling (a clone of) oneself with less work passed.